# React app redirecting to 404 if not going to main page

Tags: reactjs

I am having trouble with some react code. The app works if I go to the main url, that main url creates a link to share the location of the user and if I open a new tab and type that url everything works and I can see the location but if I go to incognito mode without loading the main page and type the generated url it displays a 404 error. Is that a problem with my react router?
Here is my code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Container, Row, Col, Button, FormGroup, Input, Label } from 'reactstrap';
import { BrowserRouter, Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';
import GoogleMapReact from 'google-map-react';
import {Firestore} from './fire.js';
import './App.css';

const UserMarker = ({ text }) => <div><img style={{width:'40px'}} src="map-marker-icon.png" /></div>;

export default class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (

      <BrowserRouter>
        <Switch>
          <Route exact path='/' component={ShareLocation}/>
          <Route exact path='/:shareId' component={ViewLocation}/>
        </Switch>
      </BrowserRouter>

    );
  }
}

class ShareLocation extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      latitude: -23.52,
      longitude: -46.88,
      error: null,
      shareId: '',
      watchId: null
    };

    this.watchLocation = this.watchLocation.bind(this);
    this.changeLocation = this.changeLocation.bind(this);
    this.startSharing = this.startSharing.bind(this);
    this.stopSharing = this.stopSharing.bind(this);
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    this.stopSharing();
  }

  watchLocation() {

    Firestore.collection("shares").add({
        created_at: new Date(),
        viewers: [],
        active: true
    })
    .then(doc => {
        this.setState({shareId: doc.id}, () => {
          this.startSharing();
        });
    })
    .catch(function(error) {
        console.error("Error writing document: ", error);
    });


  }

  startSharing() {
    this.setState({
      watchId: navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(
        (position) => {
          this.changeLocation(position)
        },
        (error) => this.setState({ error: error.message }),
        { enableHighAccuracy: true, timeout: 20000, maximumAge: 1000, distanceFilter: 10 },
      )
    });
  }

  changeLocation(position) {
    Firestore.collection("shares").doc(this.state.shareId).collection("history").add({
        created_at: new Date(),
        position: {
          latitude: position.coords.latitude,
          longitude: position.coords.longitude,
          accuracy: position.coords.accuracy,
          altitude: position.coords.altitude,
          altitudeAccuracy: position.coords.altitudeAccuracy,
          speed: position.coords.speed
        }
    });

    this.setState({
      latitude: position.coords.latitude,
      longitude: position.coords.longitude,
      error: null,
    });
  }

  stopSharing() {
    if (this.state.watchId) {
      navigator.geolocation.clearWatch(this.state.watchId);
      this.setState({whatchId: null});
    }
  }

  render() {

    if (!this.state.watchId)
      return (
        <Container className="my-5">
          <Row>
            <Col className="text-center">
              <Button onClick={this.watchLocation}>Share location</Button>
            </Col>
          </Row>
        </Container>
      );


    return (
      <div>
        <GoogleMapReact
          bootstrapURLKeys={{ key: 'DELETED' }}
          defaultZoom={18}
          defaultCenter={{lat: -23.52, lng: -46.88}}
          center={{lat: this.state.latitude, lng: this.state.longitude}}
          style={{minHeight:'800px'}}
        >
          <UserMarker
            lat={this.state.latitude}
            lng={this.state.longitude}
            text={'You are here'}
          />
        </GoogleMapReact>

        <div className="controls-top">
          <Button onClick={this.stopSharing}>Stop sharing</Button>
          <Input readOnly={true} type="text" value={'https://'+window.location.hostname+'/'+this.state.shareId} />
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

class ViewLocation extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      latitude: -23.52,
      longitude: -46.88
    };
  }

  componentWillMount() {
    var that = this;
    Firestore.collection("shares").doc(this.props.match.params.shareId).collection("history").orderBy("created_at", "asc").onSnapshot((querySnapshot) => {
      querySnapshot.forEach(function(doc) {
        console.log(doc.data());
        that.setState(doc.data());
      });
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <GoogleMapReact
          bootstrapURLKeys={{ key: 'DELETED' }}
          defaultZoom={18}
          defaultCenter={{lat: -23.52, lng: -46.88}}
          center={{lat: this.state.position?this.state.position.latitude:-23.52, lng: this.state.position?this.state.position.longitude:-46.88}}
          style={{minHeight:'300px'}}
        >
          <UserMarker
            lat={this.state.position?this.state.position.latitude:-23.52}
            lng={this.state.position?this.state.position.longitude:-46.88}
            text={'The object is here'}
          />
        </GoogleMapReact>
        <div className="controls-top">
          <strong>Speed:</strong> {this.state.position && this.state.position.speed?this.state.position.speed:'not available'} {' '}
          <strong>Accuracy:</strong> {this.state.position && this.state.position.accuracy?this.state.position.accuracy:'0'}%
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: What server are you using to serve this? More than likely your server needs to be configured to route all URLs to your index.html page. This discusses it for React Router and hosting the app on Nginx: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45598779/react-router-browserrouter-leads-to-404-not-found-nginx-error-when-going-to

Comment: Have you tried to put `"homepage": "/"` in your package.json file?

Comment: Are you using CRA or a manual config of Webpack?

Comment: Im using firebase to host the app. If I route all urls to the index.html is my url.com/GENERATEDURL still going to work?