# React-Router returns 404 when I specify a page in the url

Tags: reactjs, nginx, react-router

When I go to mywebsite.com I see my website. However when I go to mywebsite.com/page then I get a 404.

I am using nginx to deliver the files and from what I read I have configured it to always go to index, but it doesnt seem to work.

Here is my nginx config:

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    server_name mywebsite.com;

    root /var/www/mywebsite.com/frontend/build;
    index index.html index.htm;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ index.html;
    }
}

server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80 ipv6only=on;

    root /var/www/mywebsite.com/backend/public;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;

    server_name api.mywebsite.com;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri /index.php =404;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }
}
```

What Am i doing to get nginx working with react router?

Comment: Have a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45598779/react-router-browserrouter-leads-to-404-not-found-nginx-error-when-going-to

Comment: Thats what I have checked and seem to have what they recommend though

Comment: Try: `try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;`

Comment: ah yes, i forgot the "/" before index.html! Thanks!