# React router dom not working after deployment

Tags: reactjs, rxjs, react-router, http-status-code-404, react-router-dom

I'm using the react router dom for my frontend routing, but whenever I refresh the page or access any URL which isn't the root or '/' the server responds with a 404, before I ran npm build the router worked just fine even if I refreshed the page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check
[React Router BrowserRouter leads to "404 Not Found - nginx " error when going to subpage directly without through a home-page click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45598779/react-router-browserrouter-leads-to-404-not-found-nginx-error-when-going-to)

https://coderrocketfuel.com/article/fix-404-error-when-using-react-rouder-dom-and-nginx

Comment: Thanks the last article was really helpful, I had tried  but wasn't restarting nginx, I've restarted it and everything works just fine!

Answer (score 0):

You should add `.htaccess` (server configuration) file to your remote Apache server's directory with the following code (forces https):

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\. [NC]
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(.+)$ [NC]
  RewriteRule ^ https://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NE,R=301]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
  RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
  RewriteRule ^(.*) /index.html [NC,L]
</IfModule>
```

Without forcing https:

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.html [QSA,L]
```

Comment: I'm using nginx