# Problem with React BrowserRouter inside Drupal site

Tags: reactjs, nginx, drupal, nginx-config, nginx-location

I have a `Drupal 10` site with one page at the following URL: `localhost:9090/my-page`. On that page, I have a `Drupal block` that includes a `React app` with its own `Browser Router`.

React **BrowserRouter** configuration:

```js
<BrowserRouter basename="/my-page">
  <App />
</BrowserRouter>
```

React **Routes**:

```js
<Routes>
  <Route index path="/demo-1" element={<DemoOne />} />
  <Route path="/demo-2" element={<DemoTwo />} />
</Routes>
```

When I access the `My Page`, the `React App` shows up, and I can use `React Router` normally, and the **URL changes**. The problem occurs when I **reload the page**; Drupal gives me a **404 error**.

Example: **localhost:9090/my-page/demo-1**

I'm using `Nginx`, and perhaps I need some extra configuration for this scenario.

**Final Note:**

React APP is embed directly inside Drupal page with **[Drupal Block Plugin](https://www.rapiddg.com/article/how-add-react-widget-drupal-8-site)**. So there is no **index.html**.

**This is an example what I exactly need:**

https://iap.unido.org/data/sdg-9-industry?p=LBY

Base is `/data` and `/data/sdg-9-industry` is some page inside `React`.

**Solution:**

For the future readers with the same problem check out those answers:

**[StackExchange - cilefen](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/316983/why-do-routes-created-in-a-react-router-that-do-not-exist-in-drupal-give-a-404-w/316986#316986)**

**[GitHub - Samuel Oltz](https://github.com/pianomansam/drupal-react-widget-module/issues/1)**

Comment: It looks like Drupal can't can navigate application to react routes.
I seems that you should make changes into Drupal router. You should change Drupal's route from /my-page to /my-page/*